# How to use Set-AzStorageBlobContent with managed identity to copy file from vm to blob storage account

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage

I would like to seek your help about how to use the Set-AzStorageBlobContent with managed identity in powershell script

In my code, I use this to login the blob storage account

```
Azcopy login —identity
```

But in the Set-AzStorageBlobContent, I will need to pass the context in it. Is that I can simply remove the context parameter?

```
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $context -File "$file" -Container "<container name>" -Blob $blobName
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i googled and got the following findings.. is it the same as using Set-AzStorageBlobContent? Thanks

```
azcopy login --identity

azcopy cp sourcefile destination
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).